# SQL*Plus won't connect to Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus, oracle-sqldeveloper

Here's the deal
I installed Oracle 11g XE on my computer.  I had no problem connecting with SQL*Plus using the system and sys users.  I also created 2 new users and I had no problem connecting with those 2.  I installed SQLDevelopper and I had no problem connecting with the 4 users mentionned ealier.

I wanted to change the default date formating so I did the next command in SQL*Plus using the user sys :

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT=‘DD-MON-YYYY’ SCOPE=SPFILE;
```

After the execution of the last command I restarted the Oracle Service.

Here's the problem...
After restarting I could'nt log with any on the 4 accounts created earlier using SQL*Plus.  SQL*Plus gave me this error message :

```
ERROR: ORA-12638: Credential retrieval failed
```

The weird thing is that I can log without any problem using SQLDevelopper.

Can someone help me fix SQL*Plus ?

Comment: If I understood correctly, it may well be the case, that the `ALTER SYSTEM SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT=‘DD-MON-YYYY’ SCOPE=SPFILE;` statement has nothing to do with the mentioned error. It may be just a coincidence that the `ALTER SYSTEM SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT` was the last statement you run.

Comment: Yes...the alter system was probably not the problem.  It was the last command before I restarted the service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a tip from Mr Burleson: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_12638_credential_retrieval_failed.htm

Please check the sqlnet.ora file. Change the following entry and try, this will work.

Original Entry

```
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS)
```

Modified Entry

```
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES=
```

Comment: Thank you very much....Now I can log to Oracle using SQL*plus.  I checked the tip from Mr Burleson before asking my quesion on stackoverflow.   I was writing in sqlnet.ora SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NONE) as mentionned in the tip and that didn't help.  Writing SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES=    solved the problem.   Again thank you very much

Comment: yeah, it seemed to be a little ambiguous for me too.